# find, xarg, Awk Problem

Tags: awk, find, xargs

I have the command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "Name, Number"}/value/{print FILENAME, "," $8}' *.txt >> out.csv
```

Which works perfectly to go through my txt files in the directory, parse the value(s) and write the final csv file with the header (Name, Number).

My issue is that I have "too many" and so I modify it with find and xarg:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' | xargs awk 'BEGIN{print "Name, Number"}/value/{print FILENAME, "," $8}' | sed 's/\.\///g' >> out.csv
```

This has worked in the past, but now I find that -- on occasion -- the header is written more than once to the final csv file. I don't know why. It does ssem to be related to the total number of txt files in the directory such that if I hit a certain number, this happens, but I am not really sure.

thanks.

Comment: `xargs` runs the `awk` command as many times as necessary to avoid the "too many" problem - the `BEGIN` block will be executed each time it does so

Answer (score 3):

The `find` will call awk in batches of files so the `BEGIN` will be executed once per batch instead of once for all files as you want. Instead of having awk called with all the files as arguments and having the shell fail with a "too many arguments" error, you can have awk read all the files as input and populate it's internal array of files to read (`ARGV[]`) from that:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' |
awk '
    BEGIN { OFS=","; print "Name", "Number" }
    NR==FNR { ARGV[ARGC++]=$0; next }
    /value/ { print substr(FILENAME,3), $8 }
' - > out.csv
```

I also tidied up a couple of things in the awk script and got rid of the pipe to sed as you never need sed when you're using awk. I changed `>>` to `>` as I assume you want to create the output file from scratch whenever the above command is called rather than appending to it.

The above assumes none of your file names contain newlines. If they do then use GNU tools and add `-print0` to the end of the `find` command and `RS="\0";` to the BEGIN section of the awk command. It also assumes your file names don't contain `"` as then the output wouldn't be valid CSV but your first script that you said works perfectly apart from the "too many arguments" issue would fail if your file names contained any of those so they must not.

Comment: It also assumes file names don't contain `=` character and as the output is meant to be in CSV format, you'd need to wrap the filenames in `"..."` and escape the `"`s in them as `""`.

Comment: That's true but the script that works for the OP (aside from "too many arguments") already has those assumptions so we know their file names don't have those issues while we don't know for sure that they don't contain newlines. I added a note about that though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I also added a fix for the case of a file name that includes `=` by not stripping the `./` till the output is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Run `find` and `awk` in a group command (i.e. wrapped in `{` and `}`) or in a sub-shell (i.e. wrapped in `(` and `)`) and print the header before running `find`.  Redirect the output from the entire group command or sub-shell to your output file.

For example:

```
{
  echo "Name,Number"
  find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.txt' -exec \
    awk -v OFS=, '
      FNR==1 { fn = FILENAME; sub(/^\.\//, "", fn };
     /value/ {print fn, $8}' {} +
} >> out.csv
```

NOTES:

1. See `man bash` and search for `Compound Commands`
2. You don't need `xargs` here - use find's `-exec` option instead, e.g. `find ... -exec awk ... {} +`.
3. You don't need `sed`, either - awk's built-in `sub()` function can be used to remove the leading `./` from the filenames coming from `find`.  BTW, `gsub()` can be used for global search and replace, like the `/g` modifier in `sed`.

Comment: He's got too many files and yet you recommend `-exec` instead of `xargs`? Why? Are you aware of the extra overhead of calling a new instance of `awk` for every single file?

Comment: @D4RIO you need to learn the difference between using `-exec` with `{} \;` and using `-exec` with `{} +`.   Are you aware that `xargs` is over-used by people who don't understand `find`? or of the bugs that will be introduced if you use xargs on filenames without using NUL as the separator? or that the only good reason to ever use xargs with find is if you need to first sort the filenames (with `sort -z`) or eliminate (or modify) some of them in ways that find itself can't do (e.g. with `sed -z`, `perl -0`, or `awk -v RS='\0'`, etc)?

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of `{} +` behaving that way. Curiously it's not mentioned on the manpage (this would help avoid over-use of `xargs`). About the bugs, `-print0` is not **that** unknown.

Comment: It's mentioned several times in the man page for GNU find, (search for `-exec`) and for BSD find. I can't find a posix find man page right now, but the HISTORY section of the GNU man page says it's occurs in POSIX.

Comment: You are right, it's just omitted in the spanish manpage for GNU's find. Maybe I will send a patch to fix that. Thank you.